# Java - Compare 2 Word-Files (.docx): How do I get the Changes and remember the Change-Location in the XML?

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, word-2013, word-2016

I Hope the question is understandable..

I am programming for my Exam in "Business Informatics" and my goal is to get All Paragraphs (w:p) that changes in an edited .docx-File in comparison to the original .docx-File.

I am using Java and my actual standing is that I have 2 Lists:

1. All Text - Attributes from the original File
2. All Text - Attributes from the edited File 
   (one List - Item / Text-Attribute = one paragraph in the document.xml which contains text-Attributes [w:t])

Please, I need any help that .. It's my first Program.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a suggestion: Since you have the original you can iterate trough both lists at the same time and compare the Strings in every iteration. If paragraphs of the modified list differ you add them to a list you create yourself.

This only works if there is the same amount of paragraphs in both versions, modified and unmodified.